# UITableView won't stay scrolled up in iPad popover

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I use a UITableView inside a popover in my iPad app to ask for user input, just like the Contacts app on the iPhone. It has 3 sections, and each section has multiple rows. Clicking on a row brings up a keyboard. When clicking on the bottom row of the bottom section, the keyboard hides the row, and when I scroll the table up, it bounces back down instead of staying scrolled up. On the iPhone Contacts app, the table stays scrolled up, and this is the behavior I want. Any pointers?

Comment: might be you r not setting the contentSize of the scroll view in the popover

Comment: Was your question answered? If not, can you provide more details, perhaps some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you are not resizing your table view when the keyboard appears. You should take a look here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html.

The section "**Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard**" is what you are looking for.

For your information, a UITableViewController automatically resizes its table view when there is in-line editing of text fields. If it's possible for you, you can just change your class to a UITableViewController and you won't have to worry about resizing.